# How to insert Line table in Java using Dynamics NAV web services?

Tags: java, web-services, dynamics-nav

Now I developing application using Java consumes NAV2015's web services but stuck in insert data to the SalesLine table for many days.

Before Java, I used .NET and can completely inserted the SalesLine like this...

```
using WebService;

SalesOrder_Service salesOrder;
SalesOrder_Service_Service service;
salesOrder = new SalesOrder_Service();
service = new SalesOrder_Service_Service();
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

service.Create(ref salesOrder);

Sales_Order_Line[] salesOrderLine = new Sales_Order_Line[1];
salesOrderLine[0] = new Sales_Order_Line();
salesOrderLine[0].Type = WebService.Type.Item;
salesOrderLine[0].Document_No = salesOrder.No;

// put SalesOrderLine into Header like this
salesOrder.SalesLines = salesOrderLine;

service.Update(ref salesOrder);
```

But now in Java I have no idea of how to insert the SalesLine into Header.
I tried the same way as I did in .NET but look like there are no method for me to put and set data from Line to Header. 
Actually it has one method named setSalesLines(SaleOrderLineList arg0); but the problem is SalesOrderLineList has only GET method.

```
SalesOrder soHeader = soPort.read(docNo);

//method for set SalesLines requires SalesOrderLineList variable
soHeader.setSalesLines(SaleOrderLineList arg);

// So, I created the SalesOrderLineList 
SalesOrderLineList lineList = new SalesOrderLineList();

// But.. lineList has only get method. 
lineList.getSalesOrderLine();  

// More information
// This is another class for set data to SalesLine
SalesOrderLine saleOrderline = new SalesOrderLine();
saleOrderline.setNo(docNo);
saleOrderline.setDescription("zzZ");
```

How can I combine all of this things together ?
Thank you In advance for your attention.

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Did you mean I can't do it like that?

Comment: No, I'm just saying the language, Java, is not spelled "JAVA".

Comment: ....  And here's an example as to [how to do it in php](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2009/05/28/handling-sales-orders-from-page-based-web-services-in-nav-2009sp1-and-rtm.aspx).  It'll be a similar approach I'm sure.  Don't forget to enable NTLM in the Navision configuration!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks team.

We finally found.

```
SalesOrder soHeader = soPort.read(docNo);

SalesOrderLineList lineList = new SalesOrderLineList();

SalesOrderLine saleOrderline = new SalesOrderLine();
saleOrderline.setNo(docNo);
saleOrderline.setDescription("zzZ");

lineList.getSalesOrderLine().add(saleOrderline);
soHeader.setSalesLines(lineList);
```